# Renaming devices (hard coded device names)

Tags: windows, bluetooth, operating-system, renaming

Is there an easy way to change the name of a device?

Lets say for example you have a Bluetooth device. And it has the hardcoded name "Sony Bluetooth Device". Is there a way to change it to "Device123" so that every other PC "sees" the device as "Device123" instead of the old name?

You can rename devices with for example Windows, but the new name appears only on the PC that you used to rename the device. And that doesn't help.

Jennifer

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the device itself.  What is this Sony device?  Bluetooth definitely allows a device to locally change its name.  But you wouldn't be able to do something over the air like from a windows PC to tell the device to change its name.  You would have to do something locally on the device itself, which may or may not be supported.